# JScrollPane does not want to scroll

Tags: java, scroll, jpanel, jtextfield, jscrollpane

I am really new to Java and this is my first project so it might seem like a dumb question.

I have tried the other solutions on this forum and on others but it didnt help me.

I am building an a system that has multiple JTextFields but I cannot get my JScrollPane to scroll down to view the other Text Fields.

I have inserted my code below:

```
    private void initialize() {

    frmBudsAndTastebuds = new JFrame();
    frmBudsAndTastebuds.setResizable(true);
    frmBudsAndTastebuds.setTitle("Buds and Tastebuds");
    frmBudsAndTastebuds.getContentPane().setName("Buds and Tastebuds");
    frmBudsAndTastebuds.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.PINK);
    frmBudsAndTastebuds.setBounds(100, 100, 1378, 706);
    frmBudsAndTastebuds.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frmBudsAndTastebuds.setLocation(0, 0);
    frmBudsAndTastebuds.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblBudsAndTastebuds = new JLabel("Buds and Tastebuds Invoice System");
    lblBudsAndTastebuds.setFont(new Font("Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold", Font.PLAIN, 22));
    lblBudsAndTastebuds.setBounds(335, 11, 309, 25);
    frmBudsAndTastebuds.getContentPane().add(lblBudsAndTastebuds);

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    tabbedPane.setBorder(null);
    tabbedPane.setVerifyInputWhenFocusTarget(false);
    tabbedPane.setBounds(0, 47, 1362, 627);
    frmBudsAndTastebuds.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
    panel.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    tabbedPane.addTab("Invoice", null, panel, "Invoice");
    tabbedPane.setBackgroundAt(0, Color.WHITE);
    tabbedPane.setForegroundAt(0, Color.BLACK);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
    panel_2.setLayout(null);
    panel_2.setVisible(false);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel_2);
scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setBounds(10, 256, 990, 332);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(panel_2);
    panel.add(scrollPane);
```

Comment: could you post the full code?

Comment: Sure.  I will edit the above code

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code above, you seem to have created a JFrame and added multiple tabs to it, the first tab being "Invoice". I am assuming that you want the Invoice tab to have multiple JTextFields and JLabels which needs to be scrollable. I would strongly advise you from using names like "panel" and "panel2". It is simply not good coding. A future developer would take a long time mapping things to other things and identifying the context.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(); 
panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));`
panel.setBackground(Color.PINK);
```

I am assuming that this is the JPanel where you would be adding your JTextFields and JLabels. The first thing you need to understand is that for JScrolledPane to work, you need to add all your labels and text fields to a Panel and add that Panel to a JScrolledPane and add that Pane to your JTabbedPane so that it is scrollable. So do it something like this:

```
JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
//Create all your other stuff for your frame.

//Create your JTabbedPane
JTabbedPane tabPane = new JTabbedPane();

//Create your invoice Panel
JPanel invoicePanel = new JPanel();

//Create your JLabels and Jtextfields and add them to your invoicePanel
invoicePanel.add(/*your object here for labels*/);

//Create your JScrollPane
JScrollPane invoiceScroll = new JScrollPane(invoicePanel,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS ); 
//Adds the scrolling in vertical direction always and never in the horizontal direction.

//Add the scrollPane to the tab.
tabPane.addTab("Invoice", null, invoiceScroll, "Invoice");


//Add the tabPane to your main frame.
mainFrame.getContentPane().add(tabPane);
```

The above code will add your tab to the Frame with a scrolling functionality. If you want to add additional scrolling to certain parts inside your tab, then create a JScrollPane and add all the items that need to be inside the scrolling area to that pane and add that pane to the panel. Also remember that sometimes, the scrolling might not work on a Null Layout so I would suggest creating a layout for every panel that you create. Hope this helps. Reply to this answer if you have any follow up questions.